# Naming of classes in an adapter API

Tags: java, api-design

I am working on a Java library which wraps an existing general purpose API in a more specialized, servlet aware API. The wrapper API consists of exact same classes as the unerlying API, but some method signatures are re-written in terms of servlet objects, like `HttpServletRequest`. The original developer followed the naming convention of prepending the word `Servlet` to the existing class name, e.g. `Connection` in the existing API becomes `ServletConnection` and `Session` becomes `ServletSession`. Is this naming a good idea, or should the classes have the same names? My question may seem a matter of taste, but I am hoping for answers based on reason. The Scala collections API, for instance, reuses class names between mutable and immutable collections.